# Mapping an arbitrary select to a relation table in sqlachemy

Tags: python, select, many-to-many, sqlalchemy

I have a many to many relation table between tables Item and Detail, defined like this:

```
itemDetail = Table('ItemDetail',Base.metadata, \
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True), \
            Column('itemId', Integer, ForeignKey('Item.id')), \
            Column('detailId', Integer, ForeignKey('Detail.id')), \
            Column('endDate', Date), \
        )
```

If I define inside table Item:

```
details = relation('Detail', secondary=itemDetail)
```

it works fine.

But I need something slightly different. The column endDate in ItemDetail table indicates which details are valid. When endDate is null, the details are valid.

So actually, I would need to have in my Item table, something like this:

```
details = relation('Detail', secondary=validItemDetail)
```

The problem is defining validItemDetail. I have tried a select statement mapping to an arbitrary class with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I did: validItemDetail = select(itemDetail.columns,itemDetail.columns['endDate']==None,[]).alias('validItemDetail')

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it then.